# How to refer to the objects created inside a loop using a temporay variable?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have following code:

```
for file_name in file_list:
    menu_item = gtk.MenuItem(file_name)
    menu_item.show()
    menu.append(menu_item)
```

How can I refer to any particular `menu_item` so that I can call `hide()` to hide it form my menu? Using `print menu.get_children()` shows object type and its address in memory.

Comment: How do you want to choose an item to hide?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best way would be to create a dictionary holding the various menu items. Since you create one menu item per file, using the `file_name` as a key to the respective `menu_item` might be sensible.

```
menu_items = {}
for file_name in file_list:
    menu_item = gtk.MenuItem(file_name)
    menu_item.show()
    menu.append(menu_item)
    menu_items[file_name] = menu_item
```

Now, you can use `menu_items[file_name].hide()` to access the menu item created for a certain file and hide it, or use `menu_items.values()` to get all the menu items.

Alternatively, if you do not want to create a separate data structure for this, you should be able to use `menu.get_children()` to get a list of all the menu items added to the menu.
The list contains the actual menu items. That it prints the "object type and its address in memory" is just how the menu item's `repr` method (i.e., it's representation as a printable string) is implemented.